# std::advance of std::multimap end() iterator by negative number crashes

Tags: c++, crash, multimap, stdadvance

My app crashed on this operation:

```
std::multimap<int, std::string, std::greater<int>> mm;
// insert elements
auto it = mm.end();
std::advance(it, -(mm.size() - 7));
```

Here is the message of crash:

```
Expression: map/set iterator not incrementable
```

What is the problem?

EDIT:
When I wrote just -1 instead of `-(mm.size() - 7)` it did not crash, why? Please consider that when I debug mm.size() is 8.

**EDIT 2:
When I write `std::advance(it, -(static_cast<int>(scoresMap.size()) - 7));` it works. It is because of the size type of the multimap, but still cannot guess what is the reason.**

Comment: I think you're in a position to answer your own question. The `size()` member function returns an unsigned value, and (perhaps surprisingly), the `-` operator on an unsigned value also returns an unsigned value.

Comment: Use `auto it = std::prev(mm.end(), mm.size() - 7);` instead of that ugly cast.

Comment: Thanks, I will use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expresion `(mm.size() - 7)` produces an unsigned value, std::size_t. The unsigned value is then negated, and according to recent C++ draft spec (N3690):

> The operand of the unary - operator shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type and the result is the negation of its operand. Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration operands. The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from 2<sup>n</sup>, where n is the number of bits in the promoted operand. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

the value being provided to `std::advance` could be converted to some value larger than `mm.size()` due to the negation rules of unsigned types.

The second expression in your edit, `static_cast<int>(scoresMap.size() - 7)`, changes the value to a signed type, int. Negating that value will get the desired value, however, the `static_cast` has undefined behavior if `scoresMap.size() - 7` returns a value larger than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Comment: `std::ptrdiff_t` may be useful here

Comment: Who it can be useful exactly?

Comment: @Narek: If you use `std::prev` as in my comment above it correctly casts the offset to the iterator's difference_type.

Comment: Oh, than yes, maybe the same thing meant Yakk. Thanks.